# QtCreator No Executable Specified

Tags: c++, qt, executable, qt-creator

I've searched this for a while and haven't found anything answered anywhere:

I have a project in QtCreator that has no compilation errors, and runs fine as a normal C++ project in Eclipse.

However, when I try to run it as a Qt app, it says it could not find an executable and I need to specify one.

As many other sites have suggested, I have searched the directories for the `.exe` that QtCreator was supposed to make (according to the other sites), but I am yet to find anything.

I'm in no rush, but have spent a long time on this and would like to move on to actually writing the Qt part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question cannot be answered. You need to provide the error messages and *specific* details about your problem.

Comment: Have you checked which executable is to be executed in the project settings of QtCreator?

Comment: I had this as well on old installs of qt when defining QT environment variables. After removing these qtcreator worked as expected.

Comment: @Laurent - That's the exact wording of the dialog that pops up. @DavidFeurle - There is no `.exe` specified, and it does not seem to be making one for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by having a QtCreator project and running it in Eclipse or running it as a Qt App but if you are looking for an `exe` file, QtCreator is probably configured to do shadow builds for your project. This means that build output is sent to a directory outside of your project source directory. If your project is in a directory called `MyApp`, then look for a directory beside it called `MyApp-build-desktop`. You should find your executable in there.

Answer (score 4):

Are you still struggling with the solution ? The most easy solution is, restore default setting by deleting file **QtCreator.ini**. After that configure project once again by giving build directory path. If you are working on Linux system, run following command to find **QtCreator.ini** file.

```
$ locate QtCreator.ini
```

It will give ouput like this

```
/home/tan/.config/QtProject/QtCreator.ini
```

Then delete the file on obtained path using following command

```
$ sudo rm -f  /home/tan/.config/QtProject/QtCreator.ini
```

Now open project once again and configure with your desired build and run settings.

Upvote if above solution helps you. Btw if I've made any grammatical mistakes, I am sorry for my english. :)

Best luck !!